# SPARQL checking for existance of single value among many

Tags: filter, rdf, sparql

I have an ttl file like following:

`<http://www.foo.com/subject1> <http://www.foo.com/tag> "disabled", "my-tag1" .
    <http://www.foo.com/subject2> <http://www.foo.com/tag> "my-tag2" .
    <http://www.foo.com/subject3> <http://www.foo.com/tag> "my-tag3" .`

How can I form a query to remove subjects having a tag 'disabled'? Subject can have zero or more tags.
I tried,

```
SELECT ?subject
WHERE
{
    OPTIONAL { ?subject <http://www.foo.com/tag> ?tagValue . }
    FILTER (!BOUND(?tagValue) || (str(?tagValue) != 'disabled'))
}
```

But this doesn't work when we have more than one tag for a subject.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The query:

```
select distinct ?s where { ?s <http://www.foo.com/tag> "disabled". }
```

Will grab all resources with a tag value of "disabled".  Then you have your list of resources to delete in whatever manner is appropriate for your application.

Comment: right...that is one way to go, I just don't want to do post-processing of the results.